# Android get event when Touch and Release

Tags: android

in simple Paint created below code, i can simply draw on that. but i can not detect event when until user is draw into that. simply i want to get event when touch that until release to stop paint.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Path drawPath;
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    private int paintColor = 0xFF000000;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
    private boolean erase=false;
    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }
    private void setupDrawing(){
        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.1f);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    public void setErase(boolean isErase){
        erase=isErase;
        if(erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
    }
    public void startNew(){
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

how to override `onTouchEvent` method to create or get event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve My Problem after create simple Interface between Activity and `Drawer.class`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            iOnRelease.onRelease(false);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            iOnRelease.onRelease(false);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            iOnRelease.onRelease(true);
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
public static void setOnReleaseListener(IOnRelease l) {
    iOnRelease = l;
}
public interface IOnRelease{
    public void onRelease(boolean s);
}
```

And use into Activity:

```
    DrawingView.setOnReleaseListener(new DrawingView.IOnRelease() {
        @Override
        public void onRelease(boolean s) {
            scroll_view.setScrollingEnabled(s);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

call **setWillNotDraw(false);** inside your setupDrawing() method to allow your view to perform drawing in overridden onDraw.

```
private void setupDrawing(){

        setWillNotDraw(false);

        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.1f);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }
```

Comment: how to call `setWillNotDraw` on stop painting??